# How are the C++11 memory barriers implemented for x86-like systems?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, x86-64, memory-barriers

I have a good conceptual understanding of C++11's `std::memory_order` types (*relaxed* vs *acquire-release* vs *sequentially consistent* ...), but I'd like to have a better understanding of how they are typically implemented (by a compiler) for x86 (or x86_64) targets.

Specifically, a comparison of the low-level details (such as important memory-related CPU instructions for synchronizing state or cache between processors) for each of the order constraints (`memory_order_consume`, `memory_order_acquire`, `memory_order_release`, and `memory_order_seq_cst`).

Please provide as much low-level detail as possible, preferably for **x86_64** or a similar architecture. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On x86 and x86_64 loads have acquire semantics and stores have release semantics anyway, even without using atomics, so all the memory orders except `seq_cst` require no special instructions at all.

To get full sequential consistency the compiler can insert an `mfence` instruction to prevent reordering of operations on distinct memory locations, but I don't think any other special instructions are needed.

Compilers need to avoid moving loads and stores across atomic operations, but that's purely a limitation on the compiler optimisers and requires no CPU instructions to be issued.

See http://www.stdthread.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=72.0 for some good information.

Answer (score 2):

Herb Sutter breaks this down for x86 and other architectures included PowerPC and ARM in his *atomic<> Weapons* talks from C++ and Beyond 2012. I think the relevant slides are in the [second](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2) part but the [first](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) part is also worth watching.

Comment: This was also very helpful. +1.